# Parsing Rss Android SDK JSON exception?

Tags: android, json, exception, rss

So I am in the process of developing an application for android that will parse some rss xml and show my the results.  I am basing it off a tutorial that I found and everything works fine up until I implement my own rss feed for it too read.  When I do this I get a `JSONException` and here is my error that shows up when I run the application:

```
    eclipse.buildId=I20110613-1736
java.version=1.6.0_21
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

Error
Sat Oct 08 12:19:39 CDT 2011
No command output when running: 'am start -n com.gamemaker.bob/com.gamemaker.bob.GameMakerNewsActivity -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER' on device emulator-5554

com.android.ddmlib.ShellCommandUnresponsiveException
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:408)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:276)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.ActivityLaunchAction.doLaunchAction(ActivityLaunchAction.java:74)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.launchApp(AndroidLaunchController.java:1146)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.clientChanged(AndroidLaunchController.java:1492)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AndroidDebugBridge.clientChanged(AndroidDebugBridge.java:870)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.update(Device.java:398)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.update(Client.java:835)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleAppName.handleAPNM(HandleAppName.java:90)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleAppName.handleChunk(HandleAppName.java:64)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.callHandler(MonitorThread.java:414)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:322)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)
```

So I am hoping this information will help me get this question answered. Here is the link to the tutorial I am using also : [Android RSS reader tutorial](http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.com/2010/08/android-rss-reader-tutorial.html)

Comment: please post a part of your feed

Answer (score 0):

By "everything works fine until", do you mean that you tested it on the original feed included in the tutorial, and that part works fine? If so, I'd recommend passing your rss feed through a validator.

[Validator](http://validator.w3.org/feed/)

And if that doesn't help, then pass the original feed that was originally working through the validator as well, and compare the two different outputs given.

And technically, you could even try inspecting the variable being passed as json content (in debugging mode) before it throws the exception and try validating that as well

[Jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Yes, I tested it with the original feed included in the tutorial and it worked perfectly. I also tested it with a few other feeds and some of the items would show up and some would have the Json exception.

I tested both feeds through the validator and it said they are both valid but the one included in the tutorial could use some changes for better interoperability. Below are the two feeds. Okay I will try a few things out and see if I can fix it.

http://globoesporte.globo.com/dynamo/futebol/times/vasco/rss2.xml
http://gamemakerblog.com/feed/